# Is it possible to access the address book with the Outlook REST API?

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I know I can read contacts with the [Office 365 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog) but I can't figure out if it's possible to fetch the contacts from the address book.

Comment: is not [GetContacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations#GetContacts) that?

Comment: I think GetContacts is for the user created contacts. I would like to get all the available contacts at the office.

Comment: I dont think that is currently possible

Comment: You may want to look at [Graph api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/contacts-operations#GetContacts) instead , that may be direction to go

Comment: You can navigate in the contacts folder, then foreach folders, get all the contacts, i won't answer because I don't know the API enough : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations#GetContactFolders